# What does "have numbers back" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The word "number" usually means total or amount, but it seems to me unclear here. I mean what total or amount is it. Could you explain more clearly what it actually means?

Ramires produces a trademark lung-busting run to beat Richards to the ball and win a corner kick out wide thanks to a late deflection. City have **numbers** back to defend and clear before striding forward at the other end through Tevez, who just delays his shot and allows Ake to block a low effort inside the penalty area.

Comment: I don't know - I've never come across this use before - but it looks to me as if it's metonymy: "number" = "player with a number" = "player". I might be wrong.

Comment: City have ***numbers = several players, more than usual*** playing from further back in their half of the pitch. When most of the team are "back" in their ***own*** half, that's essentially ***defensive*** play (you send more players ***forward*** into the opposing team's half when you're playing an ***attacking*** strategy).

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks a lot for the great explanation. I get it now. Very clear

Comment: What will have prompted the commentator to (rather unusually) use ***numbers*** like that is the fact that we *do* quite naturally use it in some closely-related "set forms". *When City advanced with their midfield players as will as their forwards, they defeated the United defenders **by sheer weight of numbers***. Or *Usually, the defenders **outnumber** the opposing side's attacking players in their own penalty box*. Plus of course [*Football is a **numbers** game*](https://collins.co.uk/products/9781426339233) (the winning side is that one that ***scores the most goals***).